# Connecting Windows Form with XNA Application

Tags: winforms, forms, xna, connection, window

I am creating a XNA application, i want to add a Windows form before starting XNA application which asks person his username and password to login, i created all this but when i Run my program it opens XNA window directly. Kindly tell me how to run XNA with Windows Form?

Comment: Is the whole game suppose to be in a form, or do you just want to have a startup sign-in procedure?

Comment: A tip if you'd like to get more answers is to perhaps mark your questions as answered, if they are and you will get more response. I see you've asked alot of questions but never marked an answer. Also, I added an example. If you instead wishes to add controls to your game, please say so and I can give you an example how to do that fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you wish to create a form in the game is up to you, but the best way to check something before starting a game is probably to put in your Program.cs file.

An example I made is this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #if WINDOWS

        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to start?", "Start Game", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            using (Game1 game = new Game1())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
        }

        #endif
    }
}
```

This prompts the user with a question if the game should be started. If you then customize this with a form of your own that instead checks some data and returns a valid DialogResult. If DialogResult == DialogResult.OK, well then the user is valid and perhaps the dialog can store the login information so that the game can obtain it (if needed) and perhaps do this after game.Run();

On the creation of a custom InputDialog, it's very simple. I have a Dynamic InputBox that I just customized for this. The simple layout for this then becomes:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #if WINDOWS

        XNASignIn signinDialog = new XNASignIn();
        DialogResult result = DialogResult.Abort;

        while (result == DialogResult.Abort)
        {
            result = signinDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.Abort)
                MessageBox.Show("You entered the wrong username and password");
        }

        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            MessageBox.Show("You cancelled the login, the game will exit");
        else if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (Game1 game = new Game1())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
        }

        #endif
    }
```

Full source code for my signin dialog:

http://pastebin.com/yVZbtxH8

Just create a class and copy it in.

Remember to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms for your XNA Project.